Failed build of C,C++ GNU GCC 14.1.0 ToolChain for M68K (windows MSYS2)
Failed to build C,C++ GNU GCC ToolChain for M68K (windows MSYS2)
with items:
GCC-14.1.0, NEWLIB-4.4.0, BINUTILS-2.42, GDB-14.2.
What fails is the compilation of GCC-14.1.0 giving error: implicit declaration of function 'coshl' (and more).
I can build the ToolChain successfully by replacing GCC-14.1.0 with GCC-13.3.0
This is the piece of script (part of my full GNU toolchain builder) that I use to compile GCC:
#----------------------------------
# Build GCC and NEWLIB together
#----------------------------------
mkdir gcc-newlib
(
   cd gcc-newlib
   #--------------
   echo "Configuring gcc and newlib (for details see build/gcc-newlib-configure.log)"
   ../../source/${GCC}/configure \
   --build=${BUILD_MACH} \
   --host=${HOST_MACH} \
   --target=${TARGET} \
   --prefix=${PREFIX} \
   --enable-languages=c,c++ \
   --with-arch=m68k \
   --with-newlib \
   --with-headers=${SRCDIR}/source/gcc-14.1.0/newlib/libc/include \
   --with-gnu-as \
   --with-gnu-ld \
   --with-gmp \
   --with-mpfr \
   --with-mpc \
   --without-long-double-128 \
   --disable-werror \
   --disable-decimal-float \
   --disable-libffi \
   --disable-libgomp \
   --disable-libmudflap \
   --disable-libphobos \
   --disable-libquadmath \
   --disable-libssp \
   --disable-libstdcxx-pch \
   --disable-multilib \
   --disable-nls \
   --disable-shared \
   --disable-threads \
   --disable-tls \
   --with-pkgversion='M68K GNU GCC ToolChain-${RELISE}' \
   > ../gcc-newlib-configure.log 2>&1
   #-------------
   echo "Building gcc and newlib (for details see build/gcc-newlib-make.log)"
   make -j $JOBCOUNT > ../gcc-newlib-make.log 2>&1
   #-------------
   echo "Installing gcc and newlib (for details see build/gcc-newlib-install.log)"
   make install > ../gcc-newlib-install.log 2>&1
   #-------------
   echo "done"
)

And this is the failure
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-cargf.o
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-catanhf.o
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-cexpf.o
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-cpowf.o
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-csinhf.o
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-cabsl.o
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-creall.o
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-cimagl.o
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-ccoshl.o
../../../../source/gcc-14.1.0/newlib/libm/complex/ccoshl.c: In function 'ccoshl':
../../../../source/gcc-14.1.0/newlib/libm/complex/ccoshl.c:43:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'coshl'; did you mean 'coshf'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   43 |         w = coshl(x) * cosl(y) + (sinhl(x) * sinl(y)) * I;
      |             ^~~~~
      |             coshf
../../../../source/gcc-14.1.0/newlib/libm/complex/ccoshl.c:43:24: error: implicit declaration of function 'cosl'; did you mean 'cosf'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   43 |         w = coshl(x) * cosl(y) + (sinhl(x) * sinl(y)) * I;
      |                        ^~~~
      |                        cosf
../../../../source/gcc-14.1.0/newlib/libm/complex/ccoshl.c:43:35: error: implicit declaration of function 'sinhl'; did you mean 'sinhf'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   43 |         w = coshl(x) * cosl(y) + (sinhl(x) * sinl(y)) * I;
      |                                   ^~~~~
      |                                   sinhf
../../../../source/gcc-14.1.0/newlib/libm/complex/ccoshl.c:43:46: error: implicit declaration of function 'sinl'; did you mean 'sinf'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   43 |         w = coshl(x) * cosl(y) + (sinhl(x) * sinl(y)) * I;
      |                                              ^~~~
      |                                              sinf
make[3]: *** [Makefile:43137: libm/complex/libm_a-ccoshl.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC       libm/complex/libm_a-cacoshl.o
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mario/gcc141_maker/build/gcc-newlib/m68k-elf/newlib'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:5304: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mario/gcc141_maker/build/gcc-newlib/m68k-elf/newlib'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:13461: all-target-newlib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mario/gcc141_maker/build/gcc-newlib'
make: *** [Makefile:1069: all] Error 2

I suppose that the problem is related to the M68K because I can compile GCC-14.1.0 without problems for ARM and AVR while for M68K I can only compile GCC-13.3.0
Please, what a can do to solve??

AFAIU, the host stuff build fine, and it's the target libraries (Newlib's libm) where the problem occurs.  Are you sure that the headers as of --with-headers are actually there? Or is math.h just missing coshl?

Yes, the defined --with-headers contains math.h and math.h contains the coshl prototype. Newlin-4.4.0 compiles correctly with Gcc-13.3.0 without any changes.

So you'll have to find out which command cmake is issuing, and then find how that header is preprocessed.

As you mentioned the problem is in newlib. From what I understand, "long double" is not fully supported for m68k and this generates some waning. The problem occurs with GCC-14 because Gcc14 considers the warning [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] error as default and "--disable-werror" does not resolve as well as passing CFLAGS='-Wno-error -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration' in configuration or compilation. I'm looking for a way to downgrade [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] to worning.

What works for me is make CXXFLAGS='...'. There's also HOST_CFLAGS. Or was it CFLAGS_FOR_HOST...?

Adding '-fpermissive' to CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET downgrade the [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] error to warning and I can now successfully build the crosscompiler. Thank you for your help.

I want to share some information in case others fall into the same issue.
M68K does not fully support "long doubles" and generates some warnings.
The problem occurs with version GCC-14.1.0 because this version treats the warning [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] as error (default) and this stops the compilation.
To complete the compilation it is necessary to downgrade [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] to warning (as in previous versions).
The only way I can find to do this is to add the "-fpermissive" flag to "CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET".
This allows you to complete the compilation successfully.
